# Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol three()

Tags: c, linker, keil

[Edit: The question is flawed, the file I described as "main.c" was actually "main.cpp" and that it why I was having an issue, calling a C function from a C++ file. The question is thus incorrect and doesn't have an answer, but if you have this undefined symbol issue, also think about checking you're not mixing C & C++.]

I'm using uVision 5 to develop a firmware, however I can't get the linker to find one of my functions.

main.c :

```
#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
  return three();
}
```

Test.h :

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int three();

#endif
```

Test.c

```
#include "Test.h"

int three()
{
    return 3;
}
```

All those files are at the root of my project, I know they get compiled as if I introduce a syntax error in them, compiler reports an error.
Also looking at the map file produced, I see that three() was removed:

```
Removing test.o(i.three), (4 bytes).
```

For testing purposes, I had --no_remove to linker command line, map file now contains:

```
0x0002ba76   0x00000004   Code   RO            1    i.three             test.o
```

So obviously, the linker is well aware of my function, and will or won't remove it depending on flags.

Regardless, it reports:

```
.\build\uvision5\test.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol three() (referred from main.o).
Not enough information to list image symbols.
```

Comment: I have just tried your code, and it builds well for me with a generic ARM Cortex M0. Are you sure that `test.c` is added to your project and get compiled?

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. The mistake was somewhere else, my question is incorrect, main.c was actually main.cpp, so the function had to be declared extern "C"... Apologies and thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Flawed question, it was actually a case of mixing C/C++, in which case you'll get a symbol missing if you call a C function from C++ without declaring it extern C.